# Two or More Instances of Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

Is it possible to configure two instances of Hangfire each with different jobs e.g

```
<appdomain>/users/hangfire
<appdomain>/developers/hangfire
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is separate queues rather than having separate dashboard URLs. First, you need to create different queues, so that when you trigger a job, it gets handled by that specific queue. http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html.

However, if you really want to have separate queues as well as dashboards, then you can separate them by schema names in your SQL connection string. This way everything about hangfire will be totally separated from each other. https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html